An eliptic Integral with 2 pairs of complex conjugate roots over the range $(0,\infty)$?
I am trying to compute the following integral:
$\underset{0}{\overset{\infty}{\int}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)\left(x-\bar{a}\right)\left(x-c\right)\left(x-\bar{c}\right)}}$
Where $a,c$ are complex numbers and $\bar{a},\bar{c}$ are their complex conjugates respectively.
There is formula 267.00 in Handbook of Elliptic Integrals by Byrd and Friedman that looks very close to this. But unfortunately, the lower limit of integration that appears there is given by $\gamma_1$, which is some function of of $a$ and $c$ to my understanding. Is there a way to compute this integral over the range  $(0,\infty)$?
Edit:
This integral works well, one just need to add the discontinuity be hand when the modular angle jumps from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

You might be interested in these notes, particularly the appendix of substitutions at the end: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~glabahn/Papers/ellipticPrePrint.pdf

Its a chapter of indefinite integrals with indefintely different forms of elliptic integrals depending on the situation of the four branch points and the contour relative to them in the complex plane. Grdshteyn/Rhyzik give the forms as definite integrals with one of the anchor point in one of the branch points including $\pm \infty$.
Your integrand has a product of two real polynomials under the square root.
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(a x+b+x^2\right) \left(c x+d+x^2\right)}} \, dx$$
The result is is an elliptic integral F of an arcsin ornated with a knot system of factors of square roots depending on the constants.
Makes no sense to use it in all generality because there are many different annulli of convergency for a series representation in the complex plane.
Gradhteyn/Rhyzik list these integrals as tables for 16 different domains,

Thank you for the quick response!
It does indeed looks like Gradhteyn & Rhyzik cover all the possible domains when there are 4 real roots or 2 real roots and one pair of complex conjugates. For this case however after some searching, I can only find one domain in 3.45 (8th edition). I hope I am not missing something

Correction - end of 3.145
